# jQuery datatable next button working incorrectly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using datatables with server-side processing.

My problem is the "Next" button from the pagination menu works incorrectly.

If page no 1 is selected, Next works OK; if page no 2 is selected, pressing next makes the table load page no 102 (iDisplayStart parameter is set to 1010 instead of 20).

This is my initialization code:

```
 oTable = $('#solutionsTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bSort": false,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        },
        "bProcessing": true,            
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("AsyncGetUserData")',           
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "aoColumns": [                                  
            //User
            { "mData": function(source, type, val){
                var returnString = "<b>Name: </b>" +"<span>" + source.userName + "</span>" +    
                    "<br/><b>Type: </b>" + "<span>" + source.roleName + "</span><br/>" +
                    "<b>Status: </b>" + "<span>" + source.isActive + "</span>";
                return returnString;
            }},

    ...................................

            //Options
            { "mData": function(source, type, val){
                var editUrl = '@Url.Action("Account", "CMS")' + '?userId=' + source.userID;

                var returnString = "<a href=" + editUrl + ">Edit</a>" + " / " +
                    "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"postDelete('" + source.userID +"')\">Delete</a>";
                return returnString;
            }}
        ]
    }).fnSetFilteringDelay();
```

And this is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult AsyncGetUserData(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {           
        var allUsers = CMSHelper.GetUsers(countries: User.IsInRole("Account Admin") ? CMSHelper.GetAdminCountries(User.Identity.Name).Select(c => c.Key).ToList() : null);
        IEnumerable<UserModel> filteredResults = null;
        string filterLowerCase = "";
        string userFilter = "";
        string activityFilter = "";
        string contactFilter = "";
        string workFilter = "";
        string addressFilter = "";

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param.sSearch))
            filterLowerCase = param.sSearch.ToLower();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["sSearch_0"].ToString()))
            userFilter = Request["sSearch_0"].ToString().ToLower();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["sSearch_1"].ToString()))
            activityFilter = Request["sSearch_1"].ToString();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["sSearch_2"].ToString()))
            contactFilter = Request["sSearch_2"].ToString().ToLower();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["sSearch_3"].ToString()))
            workFilter = Request["sSearch_3"].ToString().ToLower();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["sSearch_4"].ToString()))
            addressFilter = Request["sSearch_4"].ToString().ToLower();

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param.sSearch))
            filteredResults = allUsers.Where(f => f.userName.ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || f.firstName.ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || f.lastName.ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || (f.City == null ? "N/A" : f.City).ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || (f.company == null ? "N/A" : f.company).ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || f.countryName.ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || f.email.ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || (f.job == null ? "N/A" : f.job).ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || f.LastLogin.ToString().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || f.LoginsNum.ToString().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || (f.phone == null ? "N/A" : f.phone).ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || (f.Postcode == null ? "N/A" : f.Postcode).ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch)
                || (f.Street == null ? "N/A" : f.Street).ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || f.type.ToLower().Contains(filterLowerCase)
                || (f.isActive == true ? "active" : "inactive").Contains(filterLowerCase)).Select(f => f);
        else
            filteredResults = allUsers;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userFilter))
            filteredResults = filteredResults.Where(f => f.userName.ToLower().Contains(userFilter)
                || f.type.ToLower().Contains(userFilter)
                || (f.isActive == true ? "active" : "inactive").Contains(userFilter));

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activityFilter))
            filteredResults = filteredResults.Where(f => f.LoginsNum.ToString().Contains(activityFilter)
                || f.LastLogin.ToString().Contains(activityFilter));

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactFilter))
            filteredResults = filteredResults.Where(f => f.firstName.ToLower().Contains(contactFilter)
                || f.lastName.ToLower().Contains(contactFilter)
                || f.email.ToLower().Contains(contactFilter)
                || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.phone) ? "N/A" : f.phone).ToLower().Contains(contactFilter));

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workFilter))
            filteredResults = filteredResults.Where(f => (f.company == null ? "N/A" : f.company).ToLower().Contains(workFilter)
                || (f.job == null ? "N/A" : f.job).ToLower().Contains(workFilter));

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addressFilter))
            filteredResults = filteredResults.Where(f => f.countryName.ToLower().Contains(addressFilter)
                || (f.City == null ? "N/A" : f.City).ToLower().Contains(addressFilter)
                || (f.Street == null ? "N/A" : f.Street).ToLower().Contains(addressFilter)
                || (f.Postcode == null ? "N/A" : f.Postcode).ToLower().Contains(addressFilter));           

        var displayedUsers = filteredResults.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);

        var result = from u in displayedUsers
                     select new
                     {
                         userID = Convert.ToString(u.userId),
                         userName = u.userName,                             
                         roleName = u.type,
                         isActive = u.isActive == true ? "Active" : "Inactive",
                         firstName = u.firstName,
                         lastName = u.lastName,
                         email = u.email,
                         phone = (u.phone == null ? "N/A" : u.phone),
                         postcode = (u.Postcode == null ? "N/A" :u.Postcode),
                         street = (u.Street == null ? "N/A" : u.Street),
                         company = (u.company == null ? "N/A" : u.company),                             
                         job = (u.job == null ? "N/A" : u.job),                             
                         countryName = u.countryName,
                         city = (u.City == null ? "N/A" : u.City),
                         loginsNum = u.LoginsNum.ToString(),
                         lastLogin = u.LastLogin.ToString()
                     };

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = int.Parse(param.sEcho),
            iTotalRecords = allUsers.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredResults.Count(),               
            aaData = result
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);           
    }
```

I searched the datatables forum and could find anything like it. If you have met this issue before or have any ideas what might be the cause, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I was implementing fnLengthChange, which was messing up iDisplayStart parameter; I needed that to change programmatically the number of entries shown as part of a state svae mechanism using cookies; I removed the fnLengthChange implementation and used state save using local storage and now it works perfectly.

http://datatables.net/blog/localStorage_for_state_saving